# The Silverlight AutoCompleteBox Styles?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight

I have been using the Silverlight AutoCompleteBox [Introducing the AutoCompleteBox](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/10/introducing-autocompletebox/) and now I was hoping to apply some styles to it, but I can't seem to get it to do what I want.

Any styles I apply just renders it invisible without errors and there is no way to debug the XAML.

I am just trying to apply some rounded corners with no luck. How do I go about doing this?

This is the XAML thus far,

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:AutoCompleteBox}">
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:AutoCompleteBox}">
                  <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="0" 
                         Padding="2,2,2,2" CornerRadius="5">
                  </Border>
              </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>            
</Style>
```

Comment: That is a ControlTemplate with an empty Border. Obviously it doesn't show anything.

Comment: @Clemens, I can't see how it is empty?

Comment: It has no child element that displays any content. Start reading here: [Customizing the Appearance of an Existing Control by Creating a ControlTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Clemens, I see now, thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A control template defines the (complete) appearance of a control and you are replacing the (entire) default template of the AutoCompleteBox with an empty Border. That's why it doesn't get displayed.

You could copy the default style/template from MSDN and then modify it as per your requirements:

**AutoCompleteBox Styles and Templates:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd728668(v=vs.95).aspx.

Note that you cannot "override" only a part of a ControlTemplate. You must the define the entire template as a whole.